# My header can not full width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to create responisve web. I will make full width header with my code in css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body { padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; }
.navbar{margin-left:-20px !important;margin-right:-20px !important;width: 100% !important;}
}
```

This html file:

```
<body>
<header>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Why my header can't full width, any allocated space on right. Please view this:
Note: I use padding on body because body text (except slider and header) want to use padding.
[image]

]: http://www.flickr.com/photos/99517249@N07/9512136615

Comment: please try to post the HTML, or a jsfiddle example of it, so we can see what's happening

Comment: @msturdy : have done to write html

Comment: you have set `margint-left` twice on `.navbar`, one should be `margin-right`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is pulling the header to the left, hence the space.. try this:

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body { padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<header>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

here's a jsfiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/msturdy/HJsLR/

This is all based on **[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**

Note, if you want it to be truly full-width, remove the `padding-left` and `padding-right` from your `body{}` css

Comment: I have try it, but failed,, If I use `code`position: absolute;`code` , the full width can full... Why?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Is this jsfiddle closer to your goal? http://jsfiddle.net/msturdy/HJsLR/2/